# Print 10 Numbers Per Line

Tags: java

I am trying to print a loop of numbers, with 10 numbers per line. Here is what I have done so far:

```
for(int i = 100; i < 200; i++) {

    System.out.print(i++);

    System.out.print(" ");

}
```

The output I get is

```
100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111....
```

I have tried creating another loop with variable j < 11 and then putting System.out.println() however that just prints 10 returns then the next number. I am trying to accomplish this output:

```
100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109
110 111 112 113...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try [ternary operator](http://java.about.com/od/t/g/ternaryoperator.htm) `?:`

If your input is fixed from 100 to 200 then you can try:

```
for(int i = 100; i < 200; i++) {    
     System.out.print(i+ ((i%10==9) ? "\n" : " "));
}
```

will output:

> 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109
>   110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119
>   120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129
>   130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139
>   **...**

[Here is Demo on IDEONE](http://ideone.com/9G92YI)

But if you input is not fixed then try ie 105 to 200:

```
int start = 105;
for(int i = start; i < 200; i++) {
  System.out.print(i+ ((i-(start-1))%10==0 ? "\n" : " "));
}
```

will output:

> 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114
>   115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124
>   125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134
>   **...**

[Here is demo](http://ideone.com/8HfwEJ)

Comment: your ?: expression is better than my.

Comment: Zaheer I think we can remove inner `(` `)` around condition, that I beleive looks less complex.

Answer (score 2):

I can't understand how can you get that output because you are incrementing i in for loop and inner body of loop also

```
for(int i = 100; i < 200; i++) {

    System.out.print(i+" ");
    if(i%10==0)
        System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Comment: there is no need in additional counter

Comment: @Raman figured it out and edited the answer. Thanks for this.

Comment: it is wrong it will put new line after first digit 100

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 100; i < 200; i++) {
    if(i%10==0){
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.print(i+" ");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 100; i < 200; i++) {

        if (i != 100 && i % 10 == 0) {
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
```

Comment: there is no need in additional counter

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    for(int i = 100; i < 200; i++) {
            System.out.print(i+ "  ");    
            if(i%10 == 9)
               System.out.println();    
    }
```

Comment: In fact you don't need "i++" but just "i".

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
      int counter=1;
        for(int i = 100; i < 200; i++) {
             if(counter==10)
    {   
counter=1;
 System.out.println("\n");
    }
    else
    {
            System.out.print(i++ + "  "); 
            counter++;   
     }   

            System.out.println("");    
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    for(int i = 100; i < 200; i++) {
        if (i>100 && i % 10 == 0) {
              System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.print(i);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
```

Comment: Nope, it prints ten numbers per line, then go to a new line

Comment: Yeah this is printing 100 on the first line

Comment: My fault, fixed the problem

Comment: I accept that there is no need of additional counter but OP`s question to print 10 numbers per line whether using a counter or not. Stop down voting and understand OP's question.